# Browser freeze when calling an ajax post / get methods

Tags: javascript, performance, freeze

I have two ajax functions which freeze the window whenever they are called.

Is there a way to prevent such behaviour ? (Pure javascript).

Here's the two functions:

```
function fetch_json_data(a)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest() }

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
        var json_response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

        for (var key in json_response) 
        {               
            if(json_response[key] != null && json_response[key].length > 0)
            {
                var e = document.getElementById(key+".div");
                e.innerHTML = "<pre>"+json_response[key]+"</pre>";      

                var e = document.getElementById(key);
                e.setAttribute("class", "active");
                e.parentNode.parentNode.previousElementSibling.setAttribute("class", "active");

                results_status[key] = true;

                if (key.match("sh"))
                {
                    quick_info.children[2].innerHTML += key + ", ";
                }

                quick_info.setAttribute("class", "show-data");

                close_alert();
            }
        }
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax.php", false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(a);    
}
```

function number 2:

```
function fetch_data(a, b)
{   
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
        if (last_fetched_element != null) { last_fetched_element.removeAttribute("class") }

        last_fetched_element = document.getElementById(b.id+".div");

        var t = last_fetched_element;
        var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
        if (xmlhttp.responseText.length == 0) response = "No Data";
        t.innerHTML = "<pre>" + response + "</pre>";
        t.setAttribute("class", "show-data");

        document.getElementById(b.id).setAttribute("class", "active");

        close_alert();

        results_status[b.id] = true;
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax.php", false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(a); // "fname=Henry&lname=Ford"
}
```

I can't tell why this is happening. the response arrive rather quickly, but still,
I would be nice to avoid that freeze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `XMLHttpRequest.open()` function. The third parameter sets Async or Normal. With Async set to `true` the browser won't freeze. With normal, the browser will freeze and wait for everything to be loaded. So change your lines.

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax.php", false);
```

To:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax.php", true);
```

Comment: [XMLHttpRequest Open](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) open(method,url,async)  ... async: true (asynchronous) or false (synchronous)

Answer (score 1):

it is because you are using a synchronous call, try asynchronous

[set the third parameter of open  to true](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)